# Chrome won’t allow installing an extension from local .crx files

Tags: google-chrome, installation, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, security-warning

I have an extension that was installed via *Load unpacked extension*. I packaged and saved it as a `.crx` file. Now, when I drag it to Chrome, it won’t let me install from the `.crx` file and pops up the yellow bar saying that installation from that web address (`file:///….crx`) is not allowed. It does this whether I drag it to to the extensions window, settings, or new tab.

How can I install extensions from locally stored `.crx` files?

Comment: Hmm, I haven’t seen any notices about blocking `.crx` files even from the Extensions page, so it *should* still allow installing extensions from `.crx` files on `chrome://extensions`. What version are you using?

Comment: version 26.0.1410.63

Comment: I’m using the same version and I was able to drop a `.crx` file on the `chrome://extensions` page and install it.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but it's working now! I think there was some weird issue going on that makes this a bit buggy?

Comment: @DonRhummy, It's very likely because your first .crx file is local-signed, while the second .crx file you tried is signed by Chrome Store.

Comment: @Synetech, I'm getting the error ["This can only be added from the chrome web store"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OrsAj.png)  , How did you manage to get it working? Are you using a `.crx` file that is self-signed or one that is signed by Chrome Web Store?